# How to portably including mysql headers

Tags: ios, mysql, linux, windows, portability

I have a library that uses the mysql library (libmysqlclient) on linux that I'm porting to windows, but I seem to run into a "problem" with where the header files are located. Under linux the headers are located under `/usr/include/mysql` (at least for Debian) so with standard include path they would be included as:

```
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
```

However when installed the library under windows the main header seem to be located at `c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mysql.h` which would require it to be included as:

```
#include <mysql.h>
```

I need to build it for iOS as well, but at this moment I don't know where the header files will be located there.

What is the normal way to solve this? Should I add `/usr/include/mysql` to the include path under linux? Wouldn't that open up for higher probability of header name collisions?

Answer (score 1):

You can determine which platform you're running on by checking for a predefined symbol.  There are a few lists of such macros floating around; here's one:

http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system

Then, you can #include a different path depending on the platform:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
#  include <mysql.h>
#elif defined(__linux)
#  include <mysql/mysql.h>
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
#  include <whatever path works on iOS>
#else
#  error Unrecognized platform.
#endif
```

If you need to do this in more than one place, then put it into one of your own include files, and #include that, which will then #include the correct mysql.h in turn.

The other option, as you've already suggested, is to set your include path on each platform so that #include <mysql.h> works.  Which one you use is a matter of taste.